# Can I apply the llvm pass to the swift code?

Tags: swift, llvm

The llvm pass was successful with the code written in c++, c, and objective c.

But I don't know how to apply it to swift.

Of course, I know that swift uses swift-frontend, not clang.

Is this possible?

If possible, I'd like to see an pass example.

Comment: What exactly are your trying to achieve?

Comment: @MartinR llvm obfuscate pass